# How to optimize dataset aggregation on top of java objects dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, aggregate-functions

could you please support me on stupid question:

I have some Java class:

```
public class ProbePoint implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private long arrivalTimeMillis = 0;
    private long captureTimeMillis = 0;
//...
}
public class Trip implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private ArrayList<ProbePoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
//...
}
```

I have `Dataset[Trip]`. I need to collect some min/max values. What would be better implementation of next:

```
public class DataRanges implements Serializable {
    private long minCaptureTs;
    private long maxArrivalTs;

}

 val timesDs: Dataset[DataRanges] = trips.mapPartitions(t => {
      var minCaptTime = Long.MaxValue
      var maxArrTime = Long.MinValue
      t.foreach(f => {
        if (f.points.head < minCaptTime) minCaptTime = f.points.head
        if (f.points.last.getArrivalTimeMillis > maxArrTime) maxArrTime = f.points.last.getArrivalTimeMillis
      })
      Iterator[DataRanges](
        new DataRanges(minStartTime, maxEndTime, minArrTime, maxArrTime))
    })(Encoders.bean(classOf[DataRanges]))
    val times = timesDs.agg(min("minCaptureTs"), max("maxArrivalTs")).head()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Java classes, the schema of `Dataset[Trip]` should be

```
root
 |-- points: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- arrivalTimeMillis: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- captureTimeMillis: long (nullable = false)
```

It would be possible to explode the array and then take the `min` and `max` of the resulting columns, thus simplyfing the code a bit:

```scala
val df = tripsDF
  .withColumn("exploded", explode($"points"))
  .withColumn("arrivalTimeMillis", $"exploded.arrivalTimeMillis")
  .withColumn("captureTimeMillis", $"exploded.captureTimeMillis")

val Row(minArrivaltime: Long, maxCaptureTimeMillis: Long) = 
  df.agg(min("arrivalTimeMillis"), max("captureTimeMillis")).head

println(minArrivaltime)
println(maxCaptureTimeMillis)
```

The code in the question assumes that the arrays in the `Trip` class are sorted: the minimal capture time is always taken from the first element of the array and the maximum arrival time is always taken from the last one. This code takes the minimum and maximum over all `ProbePoint`s, so the logic is slightly different.